# Using the Entity Framework and ADO in a hybrid setting for transition?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0

We have an app in ASP.NET MVC 3 that, due to legacy and porting reasons, is written entirely using traditional ADO.NET for the data layer.

I am now tasked with adding some reporting to this website, and the reports can result in some extremely complicated queries.

Are there any pitfalls in using the EF Power Tools to reverse-engineer a code first model and using it side-by-side with our current ADO.NET model? Doing so would allow me to use LINQ for querying the data I need, greatly speeding up the time required to write each report. I would need to shut off data context initialization, as we have our current model do that, but are there any glaring risks or problems associated with trying to do this?

If it's of any relevance (I know EF 5 has a ton of new features), we are using .NET 4 and will begin moving to .NET 4.5 as soon as it launches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a very sensible thing to do. You could also use a database-first model, which you can refresh whenever the database changes and which does not try to initialize a database.

Since you will use the context read-only you can optimize the query process by setting the [MergeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.mergeoption.aspx) property of `ObjectQuery`s to `MergeOption.NoTracking`. This reduces overhead because the context will not track changes of the generated objects.

A problem might be that there is more maintenance if the database changes, but I think the absence of walls of boiler-plate query code for reporting on the old data layer far outweighs that.

One day :) you may even decide to use the EF model to display data that users want to filter in the UI and use the old data layer for CUD commands. (a bit like CQRS).